# C# - When you have multiple parameters with default values, why are double quotes needed

Tags: c#, parameters, default-value

I am brand new, its my first question.  Sorry for my formatting.
Is there a reason that in the following code when MyMethod() is called that the argument needs to be placed in double quotation marks?

I get an error CS0103 when I try to run it without the quotes, but I don't understand why the variable name alone isn't enough.

Thank you

```
static void MyMethod(string child1 = "Liam", string child2 = "Jenny", string child3 = "John")
{
  Console.WriteLine(child3);
}

static void Main(string[] args)

    {
      MyMethod("child3");
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand: where is `child3` variable that you would want to pass? You are currently passing a literal string

Comment: Might be useful to reference the site that you grabbed the example off to give more context about what you're trying to achieve - https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_method_parameters.asp

Comment: Yeah that would have been good idea.  I will remember for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `child3` variable is defined in the `MyMethod` method, so it is only available in that context. You cannot access the `child3` variable outside the `MyMethod` method. The `Main` method does not know anything about a variable named `child3`.

If you want to pass data to the `MyMethod` method, you have two options:

## Option #1: Literal String

This is what you are doing today: passing a literal string of text.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyMethod("Hello, World!");
}
```

## Option #2: Variable

As I said above, the `Main` method does not have access to the variables defined in the `MyMethod` method, such as `child3`. So we declare a new variable in the `Main` method. This variable holds the text `Hello, World!`, which is then passed to the `MyMethod` method.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myVariable = "Hello, World!";
    MyMethod(myVariable);
}
```

In both of these examples, the text `Hello, World!` will be passed to the `MyMethod` method, where it will be available in the `child1` variable. So `MyMethod` will process with three variable values:

- `child1`: `Hello, World!` (because we pass this value from the `Main` method)
- `child2`: `Jenny` (because we do not pass a second argument, so the default value is used)
- `child3`: `John` (because we do not pass a third argument, so the default value is used)

Comment: you have option 3: `MyMethod(myVariable + "Hello, World!");`

Answer (score 0):

In C# literal strings are always wrapped in double quotes so that the compiler knows it is a literal string and not a a variable name. So, if you remove the quotes from the string you are passing to MyMethod, the compiler gets confused because it cannot find a variable called child3.
When the compiler sees "child3" it interprets it as a string, but when it sees child3 it interprets it as a variable called "child3" that could contain any string.

Answer (score 0):

Your program did not print John out to the console because it was "obeying your instruction to print child3 when you wrote `MyMethod("child3")`" - this is not an instruction to print the contents of the child3 argument.

It printed "John" out because it always prints `child3` and the default value of `child3` is "John" if you don't supply a different value for it

Put this:

```
static void MyMethod(string child1 = "Liam", string child2 = "Jenny", string child3 = "John")
{
  Console.WriteLine("value of child1 argument:" + child1);
  Console.WriteLine("value of child2 argument:" + child2);
  Console.WriteLine("value of child3 argument:" + child3);
}
```

Then try putting some of these in your main:

```
MyMethod();                             
MyMethod("child3");                     
MyMethod("a");
MyMethod("a", "b");
MyMethod("a", "b", "c");
MyMethod(child3: "d");
MyMethod(child2: "d");
MyMethod(child3: "e", child2: "f");
```

You'll see what's going on